LaTeX psplot and multido
I tried to mix multido with psplot and I get an postscipt error:
Error: /undefined in -3.0def
I understand that \r will ignore the space after the command but if I type \relax or {} these end up in the postscrip code and result in other errors like -3.0\relax is undefined.
So how to do it right?
Reduced example:
\documentclass[border={5pt 5pt 5pt 5pt}]{standalone} % left bottom right top]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)
\psaxes[Dy=1,showorigin=false,labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,labelsep=2pt]{->}%
(0,0)(-2.5,-2.5)(2.5,2.5)[$x$ ,-90][$\ y$,-50]

\psplot[plotpoints=200]{-2.5}{2.5}{ x 2 exp 1 sub}

\multido{\r=-3+0.5}{10}{
 \psplot[plotpoints=2]{-2.5}{2.5}{ /nn \r def 2  x nn mul mul nn dup mul sub 1 sub}
}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}


TeX macros without argument swallow the space that follows (as it is indicated by the PostScript error). In order to fix, try \r\space def in the \psplot body,

Ok {}, \relax does not work but \space does.
Thank you very much!!!
